# MySQL - How to search a single character with fulltext index

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

We have an InnoDB table `post`, and create a FULLTEXT index on two column `title` & `content` with **ngram** parser.
Most of the data is Chinese characters, but contains some Japanese and English characters.

We use **MySQL 8.0.15** and I already set the `innodb_ft_min_token_size` value to 1. Now I want to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE MATCH (`title`, `content`) AGAINST ('e');

expected result:
title          content
------------------------
Food           noodle
```

or real-case example:

```
SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE MATCH (`title`, `content`) AGAINST ('麵');

expected result:
title           content
------------------------
本週推薦美食     到底該吃飯還是麵
```

It doesn't make sense in English, but sometime a single character has meaning in Chinese.
However, when I search a single character, it returns me an empty set. Only for some special characters, like Japanese character `す` and `し`, return a few results in boolean mode (it doesn't return all rows that contain the character).

I tried to use wildcard operator and query in boolean mode, but it is not working when the searching character is the last character of a sentence.

I also tried to set `ngram_token_size` to 1. It presents a strange result: all general search queries return nothing and those special characters still work as mentioned above. But if I search those special characters with `WITH QUERY EXPANSION` syntax, this time it will return more results than boolean mode (I'm not sure if these are all rows that contain the character).

Is it possible to use full-text search with a single character?

Comment: `innodb_ft_min_token_size` has no effect for ngram parser. Did you recreate the index after changing the ngram size to 1 (and restarting the server)? Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: Yes, after changing the setting, I reboot the server (also use `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ngram_token_size'` to make sure it is effective), then rebuild the index. And the table uses InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it is a special case for CJK language or ngram parser. **It seems that create/rebuild the full-text index in a specific order will cause certain problems.**

It is all well if I build the full-text index when creating a table, and insert data afterwards.

Nevertheless, in my case, the table already existed some data. Then I use `ALTER TABLE post ADD FULLTEXT ft_search_index(title, CONTENT) WITH PARSER ngram;` to build the index.
*(There is an another issue if I follow this sequence to build the index, some searching queries can't match all expected results in boolean mode)*

---

#### **Back to the question...**

**Yes, it is possible to use full-text search with a single character. You should set `ngram_token_size` to 1.**

However, there are some problems when rebuilding the index.

According to the [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html), after changing the setting, I can use `ALTER TABLE` to rebuild the index.
But no matter what I use this syntax

```
ALTER TABLE post DROP INDEX ft_search_index, ADD FULLTEXT ft_search_index(title, content) WITH parser ngram;
```

*(It caused the situation what I mentioned in the question)*

or split it into two sentences

```
ALTER TABLE post DROP INDEX ft_search_index;
ALTER TABLE post ADD FULLTEXT ft_search_index(title, content) WITH parser ngram;
```

*(After executing these two sentences, I can use a full-text query with a single character, but with more characters, it is still possible not to match all expected results in boolean mode as stated above)*,

**both of them can not work well.**

---

### **Here is my solution:**

After that, I try to ran the `OPTIMIZE` syntax to rebuild the index (As mentioned in the [document](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html), this will also rebuild the index).

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE post;
```

It is working without those problems.

(Check [`innodb_optimize_fulltext_only`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_optimize_fulltext_only) and [`innodb_ft_num_word_optimize`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_num_word_optimize) before running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` for large table)

Answer (score 0):

There is actually only a limited number of problems that could cause this behaviour for an ngram-parser:

- [`ngram_token_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ngram_token_size) has to be set to `1` (in the configuration file or as a startup parameter, it is no dynamic variable), and requires a server restart.  Verify with `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ngram_token_size'` that the setting is active. [`innodb_ft_min_token_size`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_min_token_size) (and [`ft_min_word_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_min_word_len) for MyISAM) are not used for ngrams, but are oftentimes the reason that very short words cannot be found in "normal" setups, so I'll mention them here for completeness.
- The fulltext index has to be rebuilt after the server restart. Verify that you are actually using `with parser ngram`.
- Natural language fulltext searches on `MyISAM`-tables have a [50% threshold](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html#fulltext-natural-language-threshold). This means that terms that occur in at least 50% of rows are ignored. For example, any search for a table with just two rows cannot produce a result
- The fulltext index for InnoDB tables is only updated after a commit. Verify that you don't do the search in the same transaction as the insert and/or check the value for `autocommit`.
- If an ngram contains a stopword, it will be ignored. By default, it only contains english words and should not overlap with chinese characters, but verify that noone changed it by checking the [`innodb_ft_user_stopword_table`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_ft_user_stopword_table)-variable (or [`ft_stopword_file`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) for MyISAM).
- Character set incompatibilies between your client connnection settings and the table column/server settings can produce unexpected (in-)equalities. (Like umlauts or case-(in)sensitivity, but I don't know if those are relevant in chinese). Try `... where content like '%麵'`. If this doesn't find your row either, this is almost certainly the problem.

The following test on MySQL 8.0.15 (with `ngram_token_size=1`) finds the row:

```
CREATE TABLE `so_ngramtest` (
  `title` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  FULLTEXT KEY `title` (`title`,`content`) WITH PARSER `ngram`  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

INSERT INTO `so_ngramtest` (`title`, `content`)
VALUES(_utf8mb4'本週推薦美食' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci, 
       _utf8mb4'到底該吃飯還是麵' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci);

COMMIT;

SELECT * FROM `so_ngramtest` 
WHERE MATCH (`title`, `content`) AGAINST (_utf8mb4'麵' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci);
```

Try to run this on your server. If this produces a result, find the deviation to your code (e.g. by adding table definition/collation settings to your question). If it doesn't, recheck all the settings in the list above (and add this result to your question).

Comment: I think I've found the problem. I used this syntax `ALTER TABLE post DROP INDEX ft_search_index, ADD FULLTEXT ft_search_index(title, content) WITH parser ngram;` to rebuild the index. Since it returns different results after a series of modifications, I thought the index already be rebuilt but it didn't.